# Настольная игра, перемещение по клеткам

Tags: c#, unity3d

**Вопрос**: делается настольная игра, игроки по очереди бросают кости и двигаются фишки, как это сделать? Обычным transform position? Но тут проблема, надо будет как то передавать туда значения выпавшие на костях , а если разные разрешения то и координаты разные будут, или я не прав? Тут еще проблема, движение не только вперед, но еще есть развилки и повороты.

Answer (score 1):

Вы ответили на свой вопрос ещё в заголовке вопроса)
Вам нужно перемещение между клетками, а не просто по позиции. У игроков должны быть созданы одинаковые поля из клеток, по которым вы и будете ходить.

1. WorldPosition(т.е. позиция на сцене) никак не зависит от разрешения экрана. Просто, у кого-то радиус обзора будет меньше. От разрешения зависит позиции внутри компонентов Canvas - т.е. внутри UI.
2. Вам не нужно передавать значений броска кубика, вам нужно передавать другим игрокам кто походил и в какую клетку. А у них уже перемещать его фигурку в центр заданной клетки.
3. Если есть развилка, то предлагать игроку бросившему кубик выбор между клетками, в которые он может пойти. После чего передвигать его в выбранную и отправлять другим игрокам в какую клетку он пошёл.

Comment: Вот это я и не могу понять как сделать) именно разметку поля на клетки, понятно что само поле будет состоять из спрайтов. Но плюс ко всему нужно еще отслеживать положение фишки, т. е. На клетках есть условия(пропуск хода, 2 шага назад и прочее) и нужно отлавливать на какой клетке остановилась фишка и выполнить условия прописанные в этой клетке

Comment: @ВладФедосеев, это очень комплексное решение) вы предлагаете чуть ли не всю архитектуру за вас придумать. Вообще, отталкивайтесь от осознания того, что игровое поле - это координатная плоскость или иначе - сетка. А значит все элементы можно хранить в двумерном массиве, где в качестве индексов используются ряд и столбец элемента в сетке. Таким образом, если сказать, что игрок пошёл в клетку 2:2 - любой другой игрок сможет найти эту клетку в массиве и передвинуть фишку нужного игрока в неё. Все настройки и прочее тоже можно хранить в данных самих клеток.

Comment: Ну с массивом более менее понятно, а как присвоить параметры конкретной клетке, в данном случае элементу массива? Допустим игрок встал на клетку 5, нужно обратится к элементу массива с индексом [1,5], и посмотреть свойства этой клетки. Как прописать эти свойства в индекс [1,5]?

Comment: @ВладФедосеев, ну, если поле у вас сразу на сцене присутствует, то создаёте скрип Cell, вешаете его на все клетки. У самого скрипта есть значения столбца и ряда, которые вы ему вручную назначаете. На старте скрипты обращаются в общий класс поля, передают ему эти значения и себя. Класс поля создаёт массив под эти клетки и назначает их в него согласно пришедшим значениям ряд-столбец.